# LinkedList default value when initialized

Tags: java

What is the default value of LinkedList when initialized?

```
What is the default value of LinkedList when initialized?
```

Thanks
George

Comment: Depends on the language I would say the defualt value of a linked list where you haven't specified the length would be a null value and the pointer to next also being null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you instantiate a `LinkedList` and don't put anything into it, it will be empty. You cannot retrieve anything from an empty list, so there is no default value so to speak.

If you create an `Iterator` and then call its `hasNext()` method it will return `false` because there is nothing in the list. If you ignore that and call the `next()` method of the `Iterator` then it will throw a `NoSuchElementException` because you've tried to retrieve something from a collection which is empty.

Similarly, if you attempt to call the `get(int index)` method of the `LinkedList` then it will throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because you've asked it to return the object held at a certain index, but an empty list does not yet hold anything in any of its indices.

Answer (score 0):

According to its [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) it depends on which constructor you use. See Constructor Summary section. It's either an empty list or a list containing the elements of the parameter collection.

If the question is what the default value of a LinkedList variable is if no assignment happens, then it's null. It's the same for all Objects.

```
static class X {
    static LinkedList x;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(X.x == null); //true
}
```